# App icon changes to default icon after installing from playstore

Tags: java, android, android-manifest

I have uploaded my app on the playstore.But when I download my app, The icon is set to the default android icon. I tried fixing the problem many times but unable to

Everything seems right on my manifest file.I have even deleted the default icon from the minmap folder. Still the problem persist.
here's my manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.hashline.rinithbinny.photoblog">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/iconfinal"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/iconfinal"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity android:name=".RegisterActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".SetupActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImageActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Base.Theme.AppCompat" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="preloaded_fonts"
            android:resource="@array/preloaded_fonts" />

        <activity android:name=".AddPostActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".UserPage" />
        <activity android:name=".SendHash" />
        <activity android:name=".PhoneReg" />
        <activity android:name=".AddSlate"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: try rebooting after uninstallation then install again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this exact problem while working on [an app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dabinu.apps.chesstimer) a couple of months ago. **I reckon it's a dimension issue.** Here's an approach that worked for me:

First and foremost, make sure the image (in your case, `iconfinal`) is a png file. I think svg works fine too.
To solve my problem, I added multiple sizes of that same image. I basically had hdpi, mdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi as well as a general `/drawable` image. After doing this, everything worked perfectly.

I really hope this helps.. merry coding!

Answer (score 1):

I would always recommend using the generator written by Roman Nurik at https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-launcher.html - it will generate your icon at all of the sizes preferred by the android os for all resolutions. this should help avoid any incompatibility issues.